# Sencha ExtJs 5 build native app

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, extjs4

Is it possible to generate android native app from ExtJs 5 project?

I've googled a lot on this topic and I am still not clear if it is possible to generate .apk file. All I could find were instructions on generating native apps using Sencha Touch and Phonegap/Cordova, but that's not what I'm looking for.

So once again, I would like to know if it's possible to package extJs 5 project (not touch) into native app.

Answer (score 0):

To create native application, you can copy the build of your ExtJS 5 application (generated with Sencha CMD) into your Android application, and then load index.html into [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) component.